# Process a value received by void onMessage() and pass the value to a different function

Tags: java, jms, parameter-passing

### Scenario

I am consuming messages from a WebLogic Queue by implementing messageListener.
The onMessage() call is successful and the message received can be printed from within the onMessage function.

### Requirement

To process this msgText as soon as it received and return the processed result to a calling method.

### Code

```
@Override
```

public void onMessage(Message msg) {

```
try {
    String msgText;
    if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
        msgText = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
    } else {
        msgText = msg.toString();
    }
    System.out.println(msgText);

} catch (JMSException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: the intention is for a result to be returned to a calling method in another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible directly because your message-driven bean doesn't have a clue which method posted the message on a message queue and generally there's no callback mechanism in MDBs.

But, there is a trick that can help. It is called [TemporaryQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TemporaryQueue.html) and it should be used as follows. In the message producer add this portion of code:

```
// OPEN CONNECTION AND CREATE SESSION
..
TemporaryQueue tempQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
msg.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
// SEND MESSAGE
..
MessageConsumer mc = session.createConsumer(tempQueue);
Message retMsg = mc.receive(); //WAITING FOR A RESPONSE..
```

In consumer (your message-driven bean) use this temporary queue:

```
Queue destination = (Queue) message.getJMSReplyTo();
// CREATE PRODUCER, CREATE MESSAGE AND SEND THE MESSAGE
```

This way you will simulate callback mechanism. Object `retMsg` should contain processed result and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to return to the result of the processed message to calling function? If so, I think it will not be possible here, since this will be an asynchronous call.

If not, please post your question clearly.

Comment: how would i print the received message from a different class?